# Do the Moksha granting cites have a deity presiding over them?

Tags: moksha, deity, cities

Ayodhyā, Mathurā, Mayā, Kaśī, Kañchi, Avantikā, Dwārāvatī are said to be the seven moksha-granting cities.  Is there a particular deity that presides over each of these cities?